# Solr 4 Lucene - Error loading class 'Solr.UUIDField'

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, schema, uuid

Trying to create a UUID field in my schema.xml, I just get this error when starting Solr:

```
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "uuid": Error loading class 'Solr.UUIDField'
```

My schema looks like:

```
 <fields>

    <field name="uuid" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
        <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="fieldName">uuid</str>
        </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    </updateRequestProcessorChain>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="address" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="city" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="county" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="lat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="lng" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
    <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="bedrooms" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="image" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <field name="region" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />         


    <defaultSearchField>address</defaultSearchField>

    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

And then in

```
  <fieldType name="uuid" class="Solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
```

From the [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey)

I'm confused as the the location on the `<updateRequestProcessorChain/>` section. I feel it shouldn't go in the field declaration part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field class is case sensitive probably, try will lower case solr `solr.UUIDField` :-

```
 <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to work this out. The next issue I had was the sample entries in elevate.xml producing invalid UUIDs, so had to remove those.